# Volley network always times out

Tags: android, http-post, android-volley

I am working on Volley POST request and i run the post in a separate thread. The issue i see is RequestFuture always timeouts immediately (in less than a second) even when timeout value was set. Could someone please help ? Server url is accessible and it returns 200 OK but RequestFuture get does not wait for server response.
Error: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.android.volley.TimeoutError

```
Thread t = new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                RequestFuture<JSONObject> future = RequestFuture.newFuture();
                JsonObjectRequest request = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.POST, url, jsonBody, future, future);
                RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(context);
                queue.add(request);

                try {
                    JSONObject response = future.get(50, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
                    if(response != null) {
                        DialogUtility.alert(context, response.toString());
                    }
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (ExecutionException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (TimeoutException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });

        t.start();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this in your code .

```
request.setRetryPolicy(new DefaultRetryPolicy( 100000, 5, DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_BACKOFF_MULT));
```

1. `DefaultRetryPolicy` is implemented in `RetryPolicy`, and `RetryPolicy` is an interface;
2. The parameter 1 in the `DefaultRetryPolicy` constructor is the set timeout, and the default is 2500. You can set it a little longer;
3. The parameter 2 in the `DefaultRetryPolicy` constructor is to set the maximum number of repeated requests, defaults to 1, and can be set to 0;
4. The parameter 3 in the `DefaultRetryPolicy` constructor is set to allow you to specify a backoff multiplier that can be used to achieve < index returns
   To avoid "> request data from the RESTful server, the default value is 1, when 1, which can be simply understood as" every time a request is long before a timeout request "long *2>" and so on.